# Set OneSignal tag in Ionic app after login

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, onesignal

I'm having trouble setting a OneSignal tag after a user logs into my app. I've included this code after successful login in my login controller, but no luck.

```
if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
                window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("email", $localStorage.email);
            }
```

I've also tried without the conditional but get the "ReferenceError: Can't find variable: cordova"

```
window.plugins.OneSignal.sendTag("email", $localStorage.email);
```

The push notification request is working. I just can't get these tags to set!

Answer (score 1):

I just solved this myself! Turns out, this is the correct way to do this:

```
var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
      console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    window["plugins"].OneSignal
      .startInit("MY_APP_ID", "gcmid")
      .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
      .endInit();
```

This goes inside the run function like this:

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform, $localStorage, $sessionStorage, $state) {
  $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {

    if (window.cordova && window.cordova.plugins && window.cordova.plugins.Keyboard) {
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.hideKeyboardAccessoryBar(false);
      cordova.plugins.Keyboard.disableScroll(true);

      var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
          console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
        };

        window["plugins"].OneSignal
          .startInit("1a1bfc10-2a06-42b8-af98-ae1d8a55665e", "gcmid")
          .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
          .endInit()
          .sendTag("email", $localStorage.email);
    }
    if (window.StatusBar) {
      StatusBar.overlaysWebView(true);
      StatusBar.style(1);
    }

  });
})
```